# Inheriting private members from base class to derived classes c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I'm trying to inherit the name,skeletonType, and numLegs from my base class to my derived class.
I have a base class named Invertebrates and derived class named Spider. I want to be able to use the private variables with the derived class from my base class. I keep getting a compiling error on line 47 and it says expected primary-expression before ','.

I'm trying to get my output to look like this:

`Spider:Brown Recluse, number of legs = 8, skeleton type = EXOSKELETON`

Could someone help me out and point me in the right direction please. Here is what I put together so far.

```
// invertebrates.h
// invertebrate specifications

#ifndef _INVERTEBRATE_H_
#define _INVERTEBRATE_H_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum Skeleton_Type { NONE, HYDROSTATIC, EXOSKELETON };

class Invertebrate {
  private:
    string name;
    Skeleton_Type skeletonType;
    int numLegs;
  protected:
    void setSkeletonType(Skeleton_Type skeletonType);
    void setNumLegs(int numLegs);
  public:
    Invertebrate();
    Invertebrate(string name, Skeleton_Type skeletonType, int numLegs);
    string getName();
    Skeleton_Type getSkeletonType();
    int getNumLegs();
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Spider : public Invertebrate {
  private:
    const string NAME_PREFIX = "Spider: ";
  public:
    Spider();
    Spider(string name);
    virtual void print();
};
#endif // _INVERTEBRATE_H_ 
**********************************************************************

//invertebrates.cpp

#include "invertebrate.h"

void Invertebrate::setSkeletonType(Skeleton_Type skeletonType)
{
     this->skeletonType = skeletonType;
}

void Invertebrate::setNumLegs(int numLegs)
{
    this->numLegs = numLegs;
}
Invertebrate::Invertebrate()
{
    name = "noName";
    skeletonType = NONE;
    numLegs = 0;
}

Invertebrate::Invertebrate(string name, Skeleton_Type skeletonType, int     numLegs)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->skeletonType = skeletonType;
    this->numLegs = numLegs;
}

string Invertebrate::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}

Skeleton_Type Invertebrate::getSkeletonType()
{
    return this->skeletonType;
}

int Invertebrate::getNumLegs()
{
    return this->numLegs;
}


Spider::Spider(string name):Invertebrate(name,EXOSKELETON,8)
{
    name =   Invertebrate::getName();
}



void Spider::print()
{
    string strSkType = "";
    if(this->getSkeletonType() == 0)
          strSkType= "none";
    else if(this->getSkeletonType() == 1)
          strSkType= "Hydrostatic";
    else if(this->getSkeletonType() == 2)
          strSkType= "exoskeleton";

    cout << this->NAME_PREFIX + getName();
    cout << ", number of legs = " << this->getNumLegs() << ", skeleton type = " << strSkType << endl;
 }


int main()
{
    Spider *sp = new Spider("Brown Recluse");
    sp->print();

    return 0;
}
```

[OUTPUT:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o8ta.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is the problem!? You didn't mention it, nor demonstrate it.

Comment: Looks ok, can you specify your problem in more detail?

Comment: You can simply add some `protected` accessor functions. Or, if there is no invariant or other constraints on the values, just make the member variables `protected`

Comment: I'm not really understanding how to achieve this. I keep reading and studying it , but can't get it yet. I keep getting an error when I compile the code. I can't get it to print what I want printed out. Right here = Spider:Brown Recluse, number of legs = 8, skeleton type = EXOSKELETON

Comment: When you say that you get an error, you should really say what error you are getting...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: IME, protected member variables are rarely useful: if there is no invariant or constraints, then you may as well go public.

Comment: `Spider::Spider(string name):Invertebrate(name&,EXOSKELETON,8)` What do you think `name&` means?

Comment: I was thinking I could get what was stored in the  memory address.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do anything with memory addresses? This is not the right syntax and you don't need it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the issues in your code :-

1. In .h file -

> const  string NAME_PREFIX = "Spider: ";

is not a valid way to initialize cont members - const should be initialized through constructor initializer list (till C++11).

Correct way in .cpp

```
Spider::Spider(string name):NAME_PREFIX(name),Invertebrate(name,EXOSKELETON,8)
{
    name = NAME_PREFIX + Invertebrate::getName();
}
```

2. In the same constructor you have written name&, which is wrong, just pass name.

> Spider::Spider(string
>   name):NAME_PREFIX(name),Invertebrate(name,EXOSKELETON,8)

Comment: Thank Everyone for helping me out. This seems to be the problem here. My teacher set the header file up and told us to make the main function work and I been working on it for a few days now. I didn't even know you could include more  variables with the base class.

Comment: `const string NAME_PREFIX = "Spider: ";` is valid syntax since C++11.

Comment: @n.m.yeah you are right, i forgot to mention that..edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally discovered what your line 47 is:

```
Spider::Spider(string name):Invertebrate(name&,EXOSKELETON,8)
{
    name = NAME_PREFIX + Invertebrate::getName();
}
```

This function has two problems:

1. What is that `&` in `name&`? That is not valid syntax!
2. You cannot access `this->name` directly, because it is private in the base class. Instead here you are modifying the local `name` argument, and that does nothing useful.

You could make the base `name` public or protected. Or you could add a `setName()` protected function.

But in my opinion this member is ok being private and read-only. The solution would be to specify the proper `name` at construction time:

```
Spider::Spider(string name)
    :Invertebrate(NAME_PREFIX + name, EXOSKELETON, 8)
{
}
```

Comment: I made those changes and my program now crashes.